# NServiceBus 5 with RavenDb 3

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I'm trying to run NServiceBus 5 with RavenDb as persistence. First I got an exception that I need to upgrade my RavenDb server, so I downloaded the latest RavenDb and installed it (3.0.0 / cdc39ac / , Build version: 3528).

Now when I run my project I get the following exception:

```
The RavenDB server you have specified is detected to be Product version: 3.0.0 / cdc39ac / , Build version: 3528. NServiceBus requires RavenDB version 2.5 build 2900 or higher to operate correctly. Please update your RavenDB server.
```

I'm a little confused since 3.0.0 is bigger than 2.5 and build 3528 is bigger than 2900 (both qualified as "or higher").

How can I make NServiceBus 5 work with RavenDb 3.0.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [open issue for this](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RavenDB/issues/54)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in how NServiceBus detect versions, you need to open an issue with them.

Comment: This is not a bug, this is on purpose in order to ensure RavenDB server versions are cherry-picked, due to the problematic release cycles of the product.